# How to parse nested Array with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys i am new of the laravel, how can i parse this output array? This is my array is coming from repeater using jquery.

```
    Array
(
    [tour_baslik] => 1. Day
    [tour_icerik] => content here....
    [lunch] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [dinner] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

)
Array
(
    [tour_baslik] => 2.Day
    [tour_icerik] => content 2 here...
    [lunch] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [dinner] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

I need parse like that but i'm stuck:

```
foreach($myarray as $key => $data){
echo $key . '-' . $data; }
```

Output must be:

```
tour_baslik - 1.day
tour_icerik - content here..
lunch - 2
dinner - 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to iterate through all items of your input, you could use a recursive function like the following:

```
function iterator($key, $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
            iterator($key, $value);
        }
    } else {
        echo !empty($key) ? "$key - " : "";
        echo $value."\n";
    }
}

iterator(null, $input);
```

Comment: How can i use with laravel this function?

Comment: It depends on the context. The easiest way will be to add it as a private function inside your controller. If you are going to use it in multiple controllers it would be better to add it in a separate file.